# Render route template into resource template outlet

Tags: ember.js

I want to render the `users/userDetail` template inside the `users/index` template outlet just to remain in the same page.

With nested resource works well but I think the route structure is more correct like in the code: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jijar/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the index route and just use the resource route.  Index is a landing page that's useful for information you want to show, when you aren't in a deeper route (aka, show this when I'm just on /users, but if I go somewhere else, don't show said info).

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="users">
  <ul>
   {{#each user in model}}
    <li>
     {{#link-to 'users.userDetail' user}}{{user.fullName}}{{/link-to}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/vuhorala/1/edit

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to achieve. Thanks also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the template in the users/userDetail route via [the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)

```
renderTemplate: function(){   
    this.render('userDetails', {
        into: 'users.index',
        outlet: 'your_outlet_name',
        controller: 'your_controller_name'
        }
    }
```

Comment: or you could use kingpin2k's example below - much cleaner